# Use PromQL/MetricsQL-Querydata for Grafana only if condition in another metric is met

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I have two similar metrics from the same job. It's the `probe_success` and `probe_http_status_code` metric of the Prometheus Blackbox Exporter. I'm also using Victoriametrics if that's of any help.

I now want to create a Grafana-panel that displays the `probe_http_status_code` of various entities but only if they have a `probe_success == 0` in the given range.

I tried to receive both metrics at once taking advantage of the `union`-functionality of MetricsQL. To only receive the labels, that allow to connect both metrics, I'm using `label_keep`:

```
(label_keep(probe_success == 0, "instance"), label_keep(probe_http_status_code, "instance"))
```

Unfortunately the Status codes are discarded, as there are already the values of the `probe_success`-metric. Is there any way to combine them in a way that all Status Codes which correspond to a probe_success of 0 are discarded? Or maybe the value of probe_success may be transformed to a label to be lateron filtered in grafana itself?

Comment: Sound like you need `probe_http_status_code and probe_success == 0`, or `probe_http_status_code and on(instance) probe_success == 0` if for some reason they have different labelsets in your case.

Comment: Yeah, that's really close! Thank you! But with that query, only code-values are returned that on the same time have a success of 0. I want to return all time data if one of the successes in the whole time frame is 0.

Comment: So something like this `probe_http_status_code and min_over_time(probe_success [1h]) == 0`?

Comment: Even closer, but not exactly it. Sometimes I have holes in my metrics because e.g. the service wasn't running. Let's say that success was 1 for 3h, then there is no value for 1h, for 1h it's 1, 1h 0 and 1h 1. `min_over_time(probe_success[7h])` only evaluates to 0 from 4h in for the last 3h. How can I "connect" the separated regions inside of the metric?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you here. But try `probe_http_status_code and min_over_time(probe_success [1h] @end() ) == 0`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you really much! Do you mind writing it in an anwser for me to accept. Else I will do it.

Comment: I'll put this as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get list of all the received http codes for target that failed at least once within the range of your dashboard use query

```
probe_http_status_code and min_over_time(probe_success [$__range] @end() ) == 0
```

Here `probe_http_status_code` is returned only if `min_over_time(probe_success [$__range] @end() ) == 0` also returned result with same labels. And the latter return result if within values of `probe_success` there was at least one zero (based on the fact that only possible values are 0 and 1).

Construct `probe_success [$__range] @end()` return range vector of length `$__range` (substituted by Grafana with actual range of dashboard) that ends on dashboard end time. `@end()` is used to pin this range selector to the end of dashboard for all values, otherwise range selector would return range vector relatively to the time of evaluated moment.